# pbs_mom problems related to log files when rebooting a Linux workstation

Tags: linux, pbs, torque

I have some problems starting up one of our workstations, and I think it is related to the TORQUE resource manager.

(the torque server is running on CentOS, the workstation on RedHat)

I need to apologize that I probably can't explain the problem more precisely, but I am currently lacking both knowledge and skills to narrow it down further. Briefly about the background of this problem: We recently had a power outage on the weekend that lasted longer than the back up batteries did last. So, basically every single workstation as well as the NIS master and slave were shutdown. Unfortunately, our sysadmin left for good last month and I am just trying to get the machines back up and running. There is only one workstation left that won't boot due to a

`pbs_mom: LOG_ERROR::read_config, config[19] special command log_file_role_depth failed with = 5`

I searched online for solutions and tried different things so far:

- restarting pbs_mom on the torque server
- clearing out the log files
- repairing the permissions in the torque-related directories

However, I am wondering about this `log_file_role_depth=5` setting in the `mom_priv/config` file itself. It looks like that it is not a valid command?! I tried to change it to `...=1` and commented it out even entirely, however, after that the machine would get stuck upon reboot at a different step, I can't tell which one is causing this issue:

[image]

(the screenshot above is from the workstation, not the torque server)

There also seems to be a related problem on the torque server. E.g., if I kill the `pbs_mom` process and restart it via

```
pbs_mom -p
```

I get the same log-file error, however the pbs_mom process is running thereafter.

[image]

Any ideas or suggestions what to try next? I would highly appreciate any feedback, I am really a little bit lost here due to my lacking sysadmin skills.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This message means there was an error in processing the mom's config file. It is located in /mom_priv/config. By default, this is /var/spool/torque/mom_priv/config. From the error message, it looks like your file has:

```
$log_file_roll_depth = 5
```

You want it without an equals sign:

```
$log_file_roll_depth 5
```

Comment: Thanks! I just went home and can't give it a try right now, but I am looking forward to test it out tomorrow. Makes a lot of sense, and I am sure that's probably the root of the problem. Oddly enough, the equal sign was there right from the beginning, a left-over from our old sysadmin. Hm, I am just wondering how he got the machines running previously with those settings.

Comment: That is curious. It is possible that the setting silently failed in some previous version and was updated to get rejected at some point.

Comment: Turns out the `pbs_mom` process starts without complaint now. However, the workstation still gets stuck while booting after `starting rhsmcertd` as shown in the screenshot above. Probably, it's something else that is not directly related to TORQUE. Sry to bother you with this, but any ideas how I can find out what might cause this problem to narrow it down further?

Comment: I'm not really sure about that.

Comment: Np, thanks anyway. Your answer definitely solved the problem that I was initially asking for